# How to keep my application "authenticated" with an AD account? c#

Tags: c#, active-directory, user-accounts

I am pretty new to C# 
I have been using Powershell scripts to code things like Unlocking an AD user or Enabling/Disabling an account. however, I do this with a different account, so I will log in with the admin account (Get-Credential) and storing it as '$cred' for example.

I am currently trying to do a similar thing in C# and I have found how to effectively "Authenticate" 
But I am not sure how to store that Authentication, or have my app Authenticated to do things with it like Disable or Unlock an AD Account.

I have this:

```
public bool ADauthenticate(string username, string password)
{
    bool result = false;
    using (DirectoryEntry _entry = new DirectoryEntry())
    {
        _entry.Username = username;
        _entry.Password = password;
        DirectorySearcher _searcher = new DirectorySearcher(_entry);
        _searcher.Filter = "(objectclass=user)";
        try
        {
            SearchResult _sr = _searcher.FindOne();
            string _name = _sr.Properties["displayname"][0].ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("authenticated!");
            result = true;
            this.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect credentials");
            this.ADUsername.Text = "";
            this.ADPwd.Text = "";
        }
    }
    return result; //true = user Authenticated.
}
```

Which just tells me that the account is correct of course, but doesn't keep my application "authenticated", any ideas?

Comment: What kind of application is this? Desktop or web or API?

Comment: This is a Desktop application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not accurate to say that your "application" was authenticated. All that was authenticated is a single network connection to your domain controller. As soon as `_entry` is destroyed, you lose that authentication.

If you want everything to happen using those credentials, then you have several options, ranging from easy (for you) to more difficult:

1. Have your users run your application under the credentials they need. Then you don't need to bother getting their username and password or setting the username and password on the `DirectoryEntry` object. Users can do this by:

   - Using Shift + right-click on the application icon and click "Run as a different user", or
   - Create a shortcut to: `runas.exe /user:DOMAIN\username "yourapplication.exe"`. This will open a command window asking for the password, then start your application under those credentials.
2. You still ask for the username and password, but restart your application under those credentials using [`Process.Start()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_System_String_System_Security_SecureString_System_String_).
3. Keep the `username` and `password` variables alive for the life of the application and pass them to every `DirectoryEntry` object you create in your application.

Options 1 and 2 require the computer that you're running this from is joined to the same or trusted domain as the domain you are connecting to. But since I see you're not specifying the domain name, I'm guessing that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a lot easier by using the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` assembly and namespace.

Add a reference to the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` assembly to your project, and then use this code to validate username/password against AD:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

// create the principal context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YourDomain"))
{
    bool accountValidated = ctx.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);

    // do whatever you want to do with this information
}
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that the `AccountManagement` namespace is always slower than using `DirectoryEntry`/`DirectorySearcher` directly. But it can make things easier on the developer. It's a trade off.

Comment: @GabrielLuci: agreed - but validating user credentials typically isn't something that's time critical, and you typically only do it once (or very rarely) - it's not a common, frequent operation - so its speed is rather secondary.